# How do I programmatically add a field to a Transaction in Drupal Commerce?

Tags: commerce

I am attempting to add a field to the entity commerce_payment_transaction.  However, when I check the database after installation which should create the field, there is no field_data_ created, nor is there any field on the entity commerce_payment_transaction.  I have successfully used code similar to the following to create field on the Commerce Order.  Do I have the bundle wrong for the instance?

Here is my code.

During the install, I create the field and its instance.

```
function commerce_stripe_connect_c_install_install() {

$field_info = field_info_field('tr_vendor_user_reference');

$field = array(
        'field_name' => 'tr_vendor_user_reference',
        'type' => 'user_reference',
        'cardinality' => 1,
        'entity_types' => array('commerce_payment_transaction'),
        'translatable' => FALSE,
        'settings' => array(
                //must have the referenceable_status defined or the user reference won't work
                'referenceable_status' => array(
                        0 => 0,
                        1 => '1',
                ),
        ),


);

if (empty($field_info)) {
    field_create_field($field);
}

$instance = field_info_instance('commerce_payment_transaction', 'tr_vendor_user_reference', 'payment_method');

//I check if the vendor_user_reference has already been created on the commerce_product
if (empty($instance)) {
    $new_instance = array(
            'field_name' => 'tr_vendor_user_reference',
            'entity_type' => 'commerce_payment_transaction',
            'bundle' => 'payment_method',

            'label' => t('Transaction Vendor User Reference'),
            'required' => TRUE,
            'settings' => array(
                    //This is required so that vendors will be available for programmatically selecting
                    //for a product
                    'referenceable_status' => array(
                            0 => 0,
                            1 => '1',
                    ),

                    'view' => array(
                            'args' => array(),
                            'display_name' => '',
                            'view_name' => '',
                    ),

            ),
            //The widget will not show up because it is hidden later on, but this is needed so that
            //a default value can be chosen
            'widget' => array(
                    'active' => 1,
                    'module' => 'options',
                    'settings' => array(
                            'apply_chosen' => '',
                    ),
                    'type' => 'options_select',
                    'weight' => '40',
            ),


            'display' => array(),
    );
    field_create_instance($new_instance);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The payment transaction entity type isn't field-able (see [commerce_payment_entity_info()](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21commerce%21modules%21payment%21commerce_payment.module/function/commerce_payment_entity_info/7)).

But you can change that with [hook_entity_info_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_entity_info_alter/7):

```
function MYMODULE_entity_info_alter(&$info) {
  $info['commerce_payment_transaction']['fieldable'] = TRUE;
}
```

Comment: I had thought about that, but I thought that fieldable controlled the UI for fields.  I am sure that this was part of the problem, but it isn't the complete problem.  I just tried setting the `fieldable` setting, and it still did not create the field.  I thought it was because the field creation happens in the `.install`, but I separated out the setting of `fieldable` into another module that is enabled first, and it still did not work.

Comment: I figured out my problem. I had misnamed the install function.  I am now able to create the fields and instances, but when I try to set the new value, it doesn't work.  I am using `commerce_payment_transaction_new` to create my transaction.  I set my new value using `$transaction->tr_vendor_user_reference=$current_vendor`.  When I save it using `commerce_payment_transaction_save`, the value does not get saved to the database in the `field_data_tr_vendor_user_reference` table.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things that you need to do to add a field to a transaction

1) set the `commerce_payment_transaction` to fieldable as mentioned above  by Clive.

2) You will need to separate the the implementation of `function MYMODULE_entity_info_alter(&$info)` from your field definition if you put your field definition in the `.install` file.  This is because the install function is run before the `.module` file

3) When defining your field in `hook_install`, you will need to set the bundle on the instance to the payment method id that you are using.  In my code above, I had used `'bundle' => 'payment_method'`.  It needs to be the payment_method identifier. This is the same value you use when creating a new transaction using `commerce_payment_transaction_new`

As an aside, in my above example I used a user_reference type. If you are using this on your transaction, when you want to set the value for the transaction, you do the following:

```
$transaction->tr_vendor_user_reference['und']['0']['uid'] = $your_uid_as_integer
```